# How can I create a Matlab struct array from scipy.io?

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

Consider the following Matlab code:

```
pmod(1).name{1}  = 'regressor1';
pmod(1).param{1} = [1 2 4 5 6];
pmod(1).poly{1}  = 1; 
pmod(2).name{1}  = 'regressor2-1';
pmod(2).param{1} = [1 3 5 7]; 
pmod(2).poly{1}  = 1;
```

This creates a struct array.  Each struct in the array contains three fields of type `cell`.  As such, we have the following hierarchy in `pmod`:

```
pmod  // struct array
|
*- struct
|  |
|  *- cell  // contains 1 or more strings
|  *- cell  // contains 1 or more arrays
|  *- cell  // contains 1 or more arrays
|
*- struct [...]
```

I'm trying to use `scipy.io` to produce the above data structures in Python, such that they can be loaded into Matlab (this hierarchy is required by [SPM](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/)).

Creating a struct is straightforward, as `scipy.io.savemat` saves any dict whose keys are all of type `str` as a Matlab struct:

```
from scipy.io import savemat

struct = {
    'field1': 1,
    'field2': 2,
}

savemat('/tmp/p.mat', {'a_struct': struct})
```

However, when trying to generalize this to a struct *array*, I hit the following roadblock:

```
struct_array = [struct, struct]
savemat('/tmp/p.mat', {'s_array': struct_array})
```

This does not behave as expected; when loading `p.mat` into Matlab, I get a 1x2 *cell* array, not a struct array.

### How can I create a struct array using `scipy.io`?

#### Notes:

1. I have tried `savemat('/tmp/p.mat', np.array(struct_array))` and `savemat('/tmp/p.mat', np.array(struct_array, dtype=object))`, to no avail.

Comment: found this post from a search about struct array to deal with the exact same problem in SPM. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `np.core.records.fromarrays` to construct a record array, which is roughly equivalent to a MATLAB struct, and will be converted to a MATLAB struct by `scip.io.savemat`.

```
from numpy.core.records import fromarrays
from scipy.io import savemat

myrec = fromarrays([[1, 10], [2, 20]], names=['field1', 'field2'])
savemat('p.mat', {'myrec': myrec})
```

When opened in MATLAB, this gives:

```
>> load('p.mat')
>> myrec

myrec = 

1x2 struct array with fields:

    field1
    field2
```

Comment: I can create an array struct using this code, but I am not sure how to create an array of structs. I tried creating the structures first and then the array, but I have a dictionary with fields that change in size, so fromarrays does not work.

Comment: @IvanFelipeRodríguez did you try creating an object array where each element is a record array?  You can create each element using the above method and then assign them to the object array.

Comment: hey @TheBlackCat. thank you for taking a look on this. I just tried initializing first every element as a record but when I run fromarrays... it raises this error " Empty data-type"

Comment: I posted my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54598286/how-to-save-a-list-of-python-dictionaries-as-an-array-of-matlab-structured-array)

Comment: This works for me except in a case like this: `myrec = fromarrays([[1, 10], [[2,3], [20, 22]]], names=['field1', 'field2'])` . I want to use this to store an array of structs where some fields of the structs are matlab arrays. I get `ValueError: array-shape mismatch`. How do I store an array as a struct field?