# How to save a list of python dictionaries as an array of matlab structured arrays?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, structured-array

I am trying to create a file to be read in a matlab enviroment. The structure in matlab looks like this

```
trx(1) = 
          x: [1×1500 double]
          y: [1×1500 double]
          a: [1×1500 double]
          b: [1×1500 double]
      theta: [1×1500 double]
 firstframe: 1
   endframe: 1500
    nframes: 1500
        off: 0 


 trx(2) = 
          x: [1×751 double]
          y: [1×751 double]
          a: [1×751 double]
          b: [1×751 double]
      theta: [1×751 double]
 firstframe: 750
   endframe: 1500
    nframes: 751
        off: -749
```

So naturally I created a python dictionary with the required fields and create a list, then used savemat. However when I loaded in matlab I only get cell arrays. I also tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212855/how-can-i-create-a-matlab-struct-array-from-scipy-io)  but the problem is that not all  of the fields are arrays with the same shapes for example 'firstframe' is an int. Then when I used fromarrays() but it complains because the shape does not match.

I am trying now to convert a dictionary to an structured array, but have not found anything related.  And also trying to create a numpy record that allows different shapes for the arrays. Any light very welcome

Comment: The mapping between Python objects and MATLAB is tricky.  You might try creating a sample in MATLAB, save it, and then `loadmat`.  That should give a clearer idea of what MATLAB needs.

Comment: I'm a little rusty on this, but I think MATLAB matrix maps onto a order F `ndarray`.  A `cell` onto an object dtype array.  A `struct` on to a structured array (i.e. one with a compound `dtype`, record array in your link).  The arrays that go into a structured array do have to match in shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Octave

```
M =

  scalar structure containing the fields:

    x =

       1   2   3   4

    y =

       5   6   7   8

    one =  1
    two =

       1   2

>> save -7 struct.mat M
```

In Ipython:

```
In [450]: dat = io.loadmat('struct.mat')
In [451]: dat
Out[451]: 
{'__header__': b'MATLAB 5.0 MAT-file, written by Octave 4.2.2, 2019-02-08 18:49:49 UTC',
 '__version__': '1.0',
 '__globals__': [],
 'M': array([[(array([[1., 2., 3., 4.]]), array([[5., 6., 7., 8.]]), array([[1.]]), array([[1., 2.]]))]],
       dtype=[('x', 'O'), ('y', 'O'), ('one', 'O'), ('two', 'O')])}
```

Here `M` is (1,1) structured array, with all fields being `object` dtype.  That way they can each have their own shape.  The scalar is a (1,1) matrix.

Comment: Hey hpaulji your answer really moved me closer. Now I am stuck with this problem . When I try to recreate the object : Setting void-array with object members using buffer.